# Url with parameters does not work in ajax but works alone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've this simple HTML / Javascript sample code ....

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Open Pronto Soccorsi</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <!-- *** References for JQuery ... -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var city= "Torino";
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://www.webglobes.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php",
          method: "GET",
          data: {municipality: city, distance:0}
        })
        .done(function(output) {
            alert("OK!");
        })
        .fail(function() {
          // handle error response
          alert("KO!");
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

... that invoke this url ...

```
http://www.webglobes.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php
```

with parameters:

- municipality=Torino
- distance=0

When I try to execute the result is always "KO" alert but if I try, in a new browser tab, the complete url that I can see in the browser console when I try to use my code

```
http://www.webglobes.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php?&municipality=Torino&distance=0
```

all works fine .... ???

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: open the web console to check what is the status code for your ajax request.

Comment: Ajax is subject to CORS restrictions as it is not a direct user action and is a logical page action that they may not be aware of.  Make sure your browser console and network tab do not have errors for the ajax request.

Comment: the status code for my ajax request in the browser console is 200

Comment: Try adding `console.log(arguments)` to your fail method.

Comment: ops ... `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.... ` is in my network tab ... sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a dataType in the request so jQuery is trying to decide which format the data is.  That's fine, but if jQuery is inferring that the data is JSON then it is trying to parse it as well.  If the data is not formatted correctly, then then you'll get a 200, but the parsing will fail and throw an error.  That may be a good place to start.